Drawing a box using high and low price of a single candle
I'm trying to draw a box at noon using the high and low of the 12:00 candle (NY time).  I'd like for it to expire each day at 8pm and redraw the next day at noon.  I'm also hoping to put a color option in the menu but that's not a big deal.  I'm pretty new to pine and am probably overcomplicating it.  Here's what I've tried and I'm getting nothing:
//@version=5
indicator("High Low Box", shorttitle="HL Box", overlay=true)

// Initialize variables for high and low prices
var float highPrice = na
var float lowPrice = na

// Define 12:00 EST time
is1200EST = hour == 12 and minute == 00

// Find the bar index of the 12:00 EST candle
var int index1200 = na
for i = 0 to 1000
    if hour(time + i * 60) == 12 and minute(time + i * 60) == 00
        index1200 := bar_index + i
        break

// Get high and low prices of the 12:00 EST candle
if not na(index1200)
    highPrice := high[index1200]
    lowPrice := low[index1200]

// Plotting the box
box.new(left=index1200, top=highPrice, right=bar_index, bottom=lowPrice, border_color=color.black, border_width=1, bgcolor=color.new(color.blue, 90))


